# Python exit(n) возвращает значение n * 256. Как вернуть требуемый код?

Tags: python, linux

Работаю в Linux. Имею два скрипта на Python. Скрипт `t2.py` вызывает `t1.py` и печатает результат его выполнения. Только почемуто результат получается помноженный на 256. Почему так происходит и как вернуть заданный код выполнения скрипта?

Скрипт `t1.py`

```
from sys import argv

code = int(argv[1])
print('Parsed code is %d'%(code))
exit(code)
```

Скрипт `t2.py`

```
import os
from sys import argv

res = os.system('python t.py %s'%(argv[1]))
print('Result is %d'%(res))
```

Результат выполнения скрипта `t2.py`

```
$ python t2.py 0
Parsed code is 0
Result is 0
$ python t2.py 1
Parsed code is 1
Result is 256
$ python t2.py 2
Parsed code is 2
Result is 512
$ python t2.py 256
Parsed code is 256
Result is 0
```

Comment: Может, `res >> 8`? Нижний байт там вроде был для идентификации сигнала)

Comment: Или делить на 256 ) Хотелось ещё знать, почему такое происходит. Но ответ уже получен, благодарю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похожий вопрос [на англ. stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649811/python-script-calling-a-shell-script-via-os-system-exit-code-256-instead-of-1/)

> Потому что `os.system` возвращает не `exitcode`, а `waitstatus`. Чтобы
> преобразовать его в код возврата, вам нужно использовать
> `os.waitstatus_to_exitcode` (или `os.WEXITSTATUS` для более старых
> версий Python).

[Из справки про `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
> the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
> meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
> value of the Python function is system-dependent.

Перевод:

> В Unix возвращаемое значение-это состояние выхода процесса,
> закодированное в формате, указанном для wait(). Обратите внимание, что
> POSIX не указывает значение возвращаемого значения функции C system(),
> поэтому возвращаемое значение функции Python зависит от системы.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ

Comment: @Olejan Пожалуйста